# PySide crashing when replacing rows in QFormLayout

Tags: qt, python-2.7, pyside

Using the following code example PySide segfaults when pushing "Add", "Add", "Remove", "Add" and due to some other sequences of interaction.

- Python: 2.7.6
- PySide: 1.2.1
- QtCore: 4.8.5

Code:

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setObjectName('MainWindow')
        self.baseLayout = QWidget(self)
        self.v_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.baseLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.baseLayout)
        self.form_layout = QFormLayout(self.baseLayout)
        self.v_layout.addLayout(self.form_layout)
        self.button_add = QPushButton(self.baseLayout)
        self.button_add.setText("Add")
        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.button_add)
        self.button_del = QPushButton(self.baseLayout)
        self.button_del.setText("Remove")
        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.button_del)
        self.button_add.clicked.connect(self.add)
        self.button_del.clicked.connect(self.remove)

        self.fields = []

    def add_item(self):
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self.parent())
        line = QLineEdit(self.parent())
        slider = QSlider(self.parent())
        layout.addWidget(line)
        layout.addWidget(slider)
        self.fields.append((layout, line, slider))
        self.form_layout.addRow("Test", layout)

    def add(self):
        for i in range(15):
            self.add_item()

    def remove(self):
        for (layout, line, slider) in self.fields:
            line.deleteLater()
            slider.deleteLater()
        while self.form_layout.itemAt(0):
            child = self.form_layout.takeAt(0)
            if child.widget():
                child.widget().deleteLater()
        self.form_layout.update()
        self.fields = []


def main():
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    frame = MainWindow()
    frame.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Is this the correct way of adding compound widgets (in this case a `QLineEdit` and a `QSlider` within a `QVBoxLayout`) to a form layout? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of adding "compound widgets" to a `QFormLayout` is to create a `QWidget` that will be the parent to that layout.

`add_item()` should rather look something like this:

```
def add_item(self):
    widget = QWidget(self.parent())
    layout = QHBoxLayout(widget)
    line = QLineEdit(widget)
    slider = QSlider(widget)
    layout.addWidget(line)
    layout.addWidget(slider)
    self.fields.append((layout, widget, line, slider))
    self.form_layout.addRow("Test", widget)
```

(And the widget also has to be removed when deleting the fields).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not creating the layouts in the right way, for example you are trying to set the layout of `base_layout` two times. Also you can check for `count()` on a `QLayout` to see if it has children:

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.baseLayout = QWidget(self)
        self.v_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.baseLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.baseLayout)

        self.form_layout = QFormLayout()
        self.v_layout.addLayout(self.form_layout)

        self.button_add = QPushButton()
        self.button_add.setText("Add")
        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.button_add)

        self.button_del = QPushButton()
        self.button_del.setText("Remove")
        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.button_del)

        self.button_add.clicked.connect(self.add)
        self.button_del.clicked.connect(self.remove)

        self.fields = []

    def add_item(self):
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        line = QLineEdit()
        slider = QSlider()
        layout.addWidget(line)
        layout.addWidget(slider)
        self.fields.append((layout, line, slider))
        self.form_layout.addRow("Test", layout)

    def add(self):
        for i in range(15):
            self.add_item()

    def remove(self):

        while self.form_layout.count() > 0:
            child = self.form_layout.takeAt(0)
            widget = child.widget()
            if widget:
                widget.deleteLater()

        self.form_layout.update()
        self.fields = []


def main():
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    frame = MainWindow()
    frame.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Do you figure there is any particular reason to use count rather than `while itemAt`?

Comment: Without setting the central widget of baseLayout (`self.setCentralWidget(self.baseLayout)`) the layout will be added as some sort of floating widget with a default size that doesn't scale with the window. As far as I know it's also necessary to specify the parent of the layout as in `QVBoxLayout(self.baseLayout)` for it to be created correctly.
Is there some other thing you are refereing to by setting the layout twice?

Comment: Well I don't know if you noticed it but when you run your code you get this message `QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to QWidget "", which already has a layout` and that's because this two lines `self.v_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.baseLayout)` and `self.form_layout = QFormLayout(self.baseLayout)` on which you are setting TWO layouts to `self.baseLayout` (and the second doesn't have effect because after that you again set the parent layout of `self.form_layout`) and NO you don't need to pass a parent to a layout to create it correctly.

Comment: I don't know why you said "Without setting the central widget of baseLayout" if you take a look at my code you will see the line `self.setCentralWidget(self.baseLayout)` is present too!, also it don't sets the central widget of `baseLayout` it sets the central widget of your main window (to be `baseLayout`).

Comment: Finally, you should not use `itemAt` because it returns the item also; count just returns the internal counter of the items present in the layout (but of course it's a matter of taste, the difference on performance should not be noted), as you can see [here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2009-November/025214.html) they use it this way too. Hope it helps.